# Combobox to filter fields in database?

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2013, datagridviewcombobox

How can I get the fields shown on the database to change depending on what is selected on the combobox?
[image]
Thanks

Comment: are you trying to sort the dgv?

Answer (score 1):

many ways to do this but i guess bindingsource would be the easiest.

just bind the grid to your datasource using a Bindingsource

then u can filter like

```
MyBindingSource.Filter = "Forename = Walter"
```

so with your Combobox it should look like

```
MyBindingSource.Filter = "Forename = " & ComboBox1.SelectedValue & ""
```

and to clear the filter

```
MyBindingSource.RemoveFilter()
```